# Java (not JavaScript) Date parsing issue: java.text.ParseException

Tags: java, timestamp

I've got a problem with the following date format: `"Jan 15 2020 11:11:50.000 +0000"`. I need to parse the date into ms.

The odd behavior is that i can't use date.parse(). The function is always failing with  `"java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Jan 15 2020 11:11:50.000 +0000";"`.

Someone got an idea how to manually parse the date or to change the date format within date.parse()?

Thanks all

Comment: This is a non-standard data. You need to do custom parsing and/or use a library like Moment.js to do it.

Comment: Can you share your tries ? This is not because a method fails that you can't use it, maybe you're using it wrongly

Comment: Hi, here is my code: 

var d = Date.parse("Jan 15 2020 11:11:50.000 +0000);

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Those are different as day and night. Also, what did your search turn up? In what way was it insufficient? Also [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please.

Comment: Which `date.parse()` is that??

Answer (score 1):

With a `ZonedDateTime` and this pattern `LLL d yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS Z` ([`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)) you'll be able to handle it

```
String value = "Jan 15 2020 11:11:50.000 +0000";
DateTimeFormatter dt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("LLL d yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
ZonedDateTime l = ZonedDateTime.parse(value, dt);
System.out.println(l.format(dt)); // Jan 15 2020 11:11:50.000 +0000
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback.

I cant use the code as mentioned below.

`code`String value = "Jan 15 2020 11:11:50.000 +0000";
DateTimeFormatter dt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("LLL d yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
ZonedDateTime l = ZonedDateTime.parse(value, dt);
newTimeStamp = l.format(dt);`code`

Any idea whats the issue here?
I get an "missing ;" Error.

Comment: Prefer `MMM` over `LLL`. For most languages they are the same, but for the few where they aren’t, `MMM` is correct. `LLL` is for the *stand-alone* month, that is, the form used when the month is *not* part of date, as it is here.

Comment: @qwertzy If I declare `newTimeStamp` a `String`, I can run the code in your comment (and get the same string back). I also got no problem running the code in the answer.